# Hide Navigation Bar when starting the Daydream service?

Tags: android, dreamservice

I am adding the Dreamservice to my app, where I would like to play a video during the dream.  Roughly the same code I use to hide the navigation control during my Main Activity

```
// Hide navigation controls
View v = findViewById(R.id.dream);
v.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

causes the Daydream to crash.  Looking at some other Daydreams, it seems like none of them hide the bar either.  Is it possible to do this?  Otherwise, the video I am playing during the Daydream isn't able to center properly.

Answer (score 2):

Try a little different approach.

```
View view = getWindow().getDecorView();
view.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | view.getSystemUiVisibility());
```

Any of `getWindow()` or `getDecorView()` might return `null`, especially when not dreaming.

Keep [the docs](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html) in mind. You might need to reapply this flag regularly. If the `DreamService` is interactive, it will not dismiss on the first input event either, just on the second.

Comment: I know this post is quite old now but since it is the only thing that would come up in a search, I want to document the fact that for me, setting `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION` wasn't enough. I also had to use `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE`. Not sure why. I should also mention that it works if you simply call it once in `onAttachedToWindow()`. It also will not return null in that case since there will be a window when it is called.